# Using regression to determine the effect of a variable on changes to pre and post measures

Tags: r, regression, t-test, psychology

I am a stats novice, using R for my psychology dissertation.

**Design:**

At T1, each participant was measured on their level of the personality trait "conscientiousness".

They also reported their level of perceived well-being.

Then, they underwent an intervention.

At T2, after the intervention, they reported their level of perceived well-being, for a second time.

**Statistics:**

A paired samples t-test showed a significant increase in well-being from T1 to T2:

```
library(lsr)
pairedSamplesTTest(formula = ~ WB_T2 + WB_T1,
       data = prepost)
```

Output:

```
   Paired samples t-test 

Variables:  WB_Avg2 , WB_Avg 

Descriptive statistics: 
            WB_Avg2 WB_Avg difference
   mean       3.169  3.006      0.162
   std dev.   0.468  0.465      0.383

Hypotheses: 
   null:        population means equal for both measurements
   alternative: different population means for each measurement

Test results: 
   t-statistic:  4.892 
   degrees of freedom:  132 
   p-value:  <.001 

Other information: 
   two-sided 95% confidence interval:  [0.097, 0.228] 
   estimated effect size (Cohen's d):  0.424
```

I want to see whether this change in well-being is influenced (or mediated?) by one's level of conscientiousness.
To do this, I have tried a regression:

```
fit <- lm(WB_Avg ~ WB_Avg2*BF_Conscientiousness, data = prepost)
summary(fit)
```

Output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = WB_Avg ~ WB_Avg2 * BF_Conscientiousness, data = prepost)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.97588 -0.24927 -0.02415  0.23182  0.82299 

Coefficients:
                             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                  -1.16709    0.85387  -1.367  0.17406    
WB_Avg2                       1.23733    0.27272   4.537 1.29e-05 ***
BF_Conscientiousness          0.62495    0.23760   2.630  0.00957 ** 
WB_Avg2:BF_Conscientiousness -0.17303    0.07442  -2.325  0.02162 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3397 on 129 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4788,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4667 
F-statistic: 39.51 on 3 and 129 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

My questions are:

1. Have I done the t-test correctly?
2. Is regression the correct
   choice for determining the effect of conscientiousness on the change
   in well-being?
3. Have I done the regression correctly?
4. If so, how do I interpret the "Coefficients:" section of the regression output?

My apologies if this is unclear or poorly worded.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is a link to my data file https://www.dropbox.com/s/ugxs3ju6cfwziwt/personality_pre_and_post.csv?dl=0

---

Thank you for the advice below, @Glen. I have three follow-up questions embedded in this edit...

I changed my model to:

`lm(formula = WB_Avg2 ~ BF_Conscientiousness * WB_Avg, data = prepost)`

Output:

```
                                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)                  0.25410    0.88564   0.287  0.77464   
BF_Conscientiousness         0.28758    0.25532   1.126  0.26211   
WB_Avg                       0.91617    0.30041   3.050  0.00278 **
BF_Conscientiousness:WB_Avg -0.07971    0.08480  -0.940  0.34900   


Residual standard error: 0.3509 on 129 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4506,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4379 
F-statistic: 35.27 on 3 and 129 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

So, if I am interpreting this right, the main effect (bottom row) is not significant. There is a significant effect of WB_Avg on WB_Avg2, but this is to be expected because the two variables are related. The p-value in the bottom right suggests the overall model is significant, but again this is because of WB_Avg and WB_Avg2 being related. So this model is not useful. **Q1** Is this correct?

I get a similar output when I change the `*` to a `+`:

```
lm(formula = WB_Avg2 ~ BF_Conscientiousness + WB_Avg, data = prepost)
```

I am still not clear on what the difference is between these two models. **Q2** Is the former looking for an interaction effect, and the latter an additive effect? If so, what does this mean in laymans terms?

**Q3** So, am I right in concluding that although the intervention led to a significant increase in well-being, conscientiousness did not influence this increase?

Comment: Be sure to add some text about the dangers of pre-post designs related to unknown time trends and regression to the mean.  In the future consider randomized crossover or parallel group randomized designs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have done the t-test correctly.  You have a significant pre-post result (although the difference is relatively small).

For the regression model, you should have the post variable (WB_Avg2) as the outcome variable (left side) and the pre variable as the independent variable (right side).

If the interaction is significant, then you'll want to focus your analysis here.  To do this, I would make two-way interaction plots to examine how the response changes based on baseline value and BF_Conscientiousness.

If the interaction is not significant then I would remove it from the model and just focus on the main effect interpretation.  Example, if the BF_Conscientiousness coefficient is positive, then subjects with higher BF_Conscientiousness on average had a larger change in the response variable.  The pre-treatment variable will probably be positive, this just indicates larger baseline values were associated with larger post-treatment values and vice versa.

Note in your regression model the intercept term is the relevant test for whether or not the treatment had a significant effect while controlling for BF_Conscientiousness.